# Trouble with JBOss finding a class: Not installing optional component "X" due to exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: deployment, ant, jar, jboss7.x, ear

I am trying to deploy an EAR file to my JBoss using Ant. I'm using JBoss 7.1.
I already have got some wars working there (using the same deploy process) but this EAR contains data about my framework which i need to work. This framework in particular uses a JAR (index-app), which i have included in it's lib folder.

This clip from my EAR build.xml shows how it reads JAR's from its lib folder (all sub-folder presented exist):

```
   <copy todir="${build.home}" flatten="true" includeemptydirs="false">
        <fileset dir="${lib.home}">             
            <include name="index/**/*.jar" />
            <include name="crawler/**/*.jar" />
            <include name="poi/**/*.jar" />
            <include name="*.jar" />
            <exclude name="local/**" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
```

When i deploy the EAR i have no problems with the compiling, only with the actual deploying generating this on my log:

```
09:33:52,452 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-15) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "scp-app.ear"
09:33:52,642 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "scp-app-web.war"
09:33:52,642 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "scp-app.jar"
09:33:52,700 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for CST_SPC_DS
09:33:52,737 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component com.t1c.modules.index.servlets.SPCCentralServlet due to exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.t1c.modules.index.servlets.SPCCentralServlet from [Module "deployment.scp-app.ear.scp-app-web.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249) [rt.jar:1.6.0_39]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentClassIndex.classIndex(DeploymentClassIndex.java:54) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:79)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [rt.jar:1.6.0_39]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [rt.jar:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_39]

09:33:52,759 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/spc]] (MSC service thread 1-6) Marking servlet SPC Startup Servlet as unavailable
09:33:52,759 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/spc]] (MSC service thread 1-6) Servlet /spc threw load() exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.t1c.modules.index.servlets.SPCCentralServlet from [Module "deployment.scp-app.ear.scp-app-web.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.newInstance(WebInjectionContainer.java:72) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1156) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3655) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3873) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [rt.jar:1.6.0_39]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [rt.jar:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_39]

09:33:52,767 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /spc
09:33:52,968 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "scp-app.ear" was rolled back with failure message JBAS014750: Operation handler failed to complete
09:33:52,983 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-15) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment scp-app-web.war in 13ms
09:33:52,993 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-11) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment scp-app.jar in 24ms
09:33:53,004 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-11) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment scp-app.ear in 35ms
09:33:53,005 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => "JBAS014750: Operation handler failed to complete"}}
```

I double checked and the JAR file containing the class SPCCentralServlet exists and it's right there in the JAR inside the generated EAR file but somehow JBoss can't find it.

Does anyone have any explanation or ideas?

Comment: I am getting the same error while writing arquillian to test my servlet ,it seems we need to have a public no-args constructor,i added it but still the problem exists.

Comment: Could you check the following link: [class loading in AS7](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7) ?

And specifically the section: "EAR Class Loading", 

This to help review your setup, validate the JBoss configuration is still the default one in regards to class accessibility within an ear, and possibly identify the issue better.

If you can provide a detailed listing of your ear content, and the jar containing the class that is not found, this should help identify the root cause.

Comment: were you able to resolve this @Rafael?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the jar containing the class `com.t1c.modules.index.servlets.SPCCentralServlet` in one of these:
1. `MANIFEST.MF` for the WAR
2. As a jboss module
3. As a dependency in `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`